# Blocking call in BackgroundService makes yet another BackgroundService not run

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, .net-core, async-await

I have 2 background services.

Both of them have a call to a method that is NOT async. This method I cannot control - I can wrap it, sure.

I wire the backgroundservice(s) up by adding them to the servicecollection:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BS1>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BS2>();
```

The execute async looks like this in each of them.

```
protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
     log.LogInformation($"Start consuming from topic: {eventStreamConsumer.Topic}");

     while (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
     {
           try
           {
                async...
                var consumeResult = eventStreamConsumer.Consume();
```

The Consume method is blocking the thread here since it's not async.

My approach so far has been to wrap the inner workings of execute async into a Task.Factory.Start, but if the Consume does not return, the thread still hangs.

I would like to truly run this on a separate thread, but bear in mind the execute async has dependencies on other instances in the class - don't know if the will be a problem?

How does this approach look like?

```
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            while (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    var consumeResult = eventStreamConsumer.Consume(); 
....
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //swallow
                }
            }
        }, stoppingToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        task.Start();

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

Comment: you should return the task you crated not just a null result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `async` works is exactly that it returns a `Task`. That's the part you're missing: instead of waiting for the task to finish or reading its `Result`, return the task itself.

Also, don't use `new Task` followed by `Task.Start`. `Task.Run` is what you actually want pretty much every time (the only exception being if you're creating your own task scheduler).